# why 'exec' is behaving different inside the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm

**My Question**

[image: question]

**My solution:**

```
import re
import math
a = input().replace("|","")
op = re.findall("[A-Z]+", a)[0]
a = list(map(float,re.split(r'P|S|M|D',a)))
expressions = {'P':'str(a[0]+a[1])','S':'str(a[0]-a[1])','M':'str(a[0]*a[1])','D':'str(a[0]/a[1])'}
exec('ex = eval(expressions[op])+"0"') 
ex = ex[:ex.find(".")+3][::-1]
l = [6]
l.extend([6+3*x for x in range(1,(len(ex)-6)//2+1)])
if ex[-1]=="-":
    l.pop()
for i in l:
    ex = ex[:i] + "|" + ex[i:] 
ex = ex[::-1] 
ex = "0"+ex.strip("|") if ex.find("|")==1 else ex.strip("|")
print(ex)
```

**The issue:**

If I wrap this code inside a function who take string input and try to return my `ex` the code shows error and nothing is changed.My question is , **can anyone explain why this works perfect alone and throws error when wrapped inside a function?**

Comment: Why don't you just (string) split on a space?

Comment: @KlausD. I know the other ways and I am able to solve it but the my question is different its about the behaviour of exec.

Comment: Trying to solve this problem using `eval`/`exec` is a bad idea. It is easier, more maintainable, and more understandable to use actual code instead of `exec`. This will avoid your scoping issues, and will help you avoid of kinds of "surprising" behaviour down the line.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa I was trying to make it as less line of codes as possible.

Comment: To me it looks like you are trying to emulate [lambdas](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions), but since they are available in Python, you can just put lambdas into your `expressions` dictionary.

Comment: It would be less readable for my team mates because I have to further built on this@JanChristophTerasa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed on `exec`s interaction with `locals`. In the `global` context (not in a function) there is no problem - `exec` modifies global variables, and you see the result. In a function the execution context is the local function, but **`exec` cannot change the local context**. The usual work around is to pass a local context where you can see the changes:

```
local_context = {}
exec('ex = eval(expressions[op])+"0"', locals(), local_context)
ex = local_context['ex']
```

Here, the second parameter `locals()` is in fact passed as a "globals" to exec. This is so stuff like `expressions` and `op` are available. Passing `globals()` here is usually not useful unless you are actually using a global variable or some other function.

The third parameter is the locals `exec` can use, and what will be populated. If you pass `globals()` as the second parameter, then usually you want to pass local variables you intend to use here as well. Passing `locals()` here will not modify your actual locals, so is usually more confusing.

Note using

```
exec('global ex; ex = eval(expressions[op])+"0"')
global ex # Need this to make sure the function knows about the new global variable in its local context
```

will work and create a global `ex` variable with the correct content. This is why `exec` works out of a function as you expect, in the global context there is no problem in modifying the current context. Note the function itself needs to be told to add a global `ex` to its local context, hence two globals.

Note the defaults is for the locals to be `locals()` and globals to be `globals()` if nothing is given, and if only the globals are given then the locals will equal that as well.

Comment: I tried  `exec('global ex; ex = eval(expressions[op])+"0"')` but it shows the error that "variable was assigned before defining"

Comment: @classicdude7 Ahh, I indeed did not post the full story. `exec` created `ex` in the global context, but the function does not know about this yet, since `global ex` was not really called in the function (again, the local context was not changed). One solution is to put another global out of the `exec` if you prefer it, though I am less in favor of this solution. I'll edit this into the answer.

Comment: can u suggest a better and more concise solution?

Comment: @classicdude7 Sure, but better not to disorganize this QA. Ask a new question with what you want and what you are currently doing (`exec`). Comment here with a link to that and I'll take a look, though knowing this site you will be answered before I get to it. In one line, probably use the Python builtin operator library (`import operator`) and have a dictionary of that (`operator.add, operator.truediv` etc...). Probably don't need a `regex` either.